# filtrar datos de un arreglo en otro

Tags: javascript, array

no estoy pudiendo filtrar un arreglo, la situación es la siguiente. es un sistema de mensajería y tengo dos arreglos uno con los que envía una persona y otro con los mensajes de ambas personas, los que quiero hacer es crear un nuevo arreglo con los mensajes de la otra persona, para esto tendría que extraer esos mensajes del arreglo donde están todos los mensajes.

Esto es lo que intente:

```
SMSTodos.map(text => {
        console.log("Global: ", text)
        SMSPersona.map(JText =>{
            console.log("local:", JText)
            if(text.text !== JText.text) allJsonChat.push({'text': text.text})
        })
    })
```

Aclaro que el arreglo contiene objetos con la propiedad text donde esta el texto, Este codigo no funciona ya que la diferencia siempre existe y se almacenan todos los datos al haber mas de uno.

Este es el arreglo local:

```
    [
        {"text": "Hola", "user":0},
        {"text": "Si, y vos?", "user":0},
        {"text": "me alegro", "user":0}
    ]
```

Y este el arreglo global, desde el que quiero obtener el nuevo array.

```
[
  {"text": "Hola", "user":1},
  {"text": "Hola, to binen?", "user":1},
  {"text": "Si, y vos?", "user":1},
  {"text": "bien", "user":1},
  {"text": "me alegro", "user":1},
  {"text": "yo tambien", "user":1}
]
```

El parámetro *user* no puedo cambiarlo en el arreglo global ya que no se puede distinguir entre los usuarios, solo se almacenan. Esto porque estoy trabajando con un *Service Worker*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías enviar algún ejemplo de los arreglos?
Si lo que deseas es quedarte con elementos de un array que cumplan con un requisito, ej: algo que identifique a la persona, podrías hacer un filter, eso devuelve un nuevo array con solo los valores que cumplan la condición.

Ejemplo:

```
const mensajes = [
  { persona: "Pablo", mensaje: "Hola como están" },
  { persona: "Julio", mensaje: "Hola todo bien" },
  { persona: "Pablo", mensaje: "Hola me alegro" },
  { persona: "María", mensaje: "Hola todo bien tambien" },
];

const mensajesPersona2 = mensaje.filter(
  (mensaje) => mensaje.persona === "pablo"
);
```

Ahora mensajesPersona2 sería igual a:

```
[
{ persona: "Pablo", mensaje: "Hola como están" },
{ persona: "Pablo", mensaje: "Hola me alegro" },
]
```

Espero te sirva, quedo a las órdenes cualquier cosa.

Comment: Claro esa es una muy buena forma si cada usuario tuviera un ID, pero en mi caso no lo tienen.

Comment: Podrías agregarles uno, sin preocuparte por que sean autoincremental, con UUID, y si no puedes modificar el original podrías hacer una copia del array por ejemplo con spread operator y luego con un for agregarle un UUID a cada uno, y trabajar finalmente siempre con la copia.. Siempre es recomendable tener un id único, porque los otros datos pueden tener duplicados fácilmente..

Comment: Comento que use este codigo para obtener un ID:   ```javascript const uid = () =>{
                const head = Date.now().toString(36)
    const tail = 
                Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)

                return head + tail
}```

Comment: Buenísimo!, después si querés mirá la siguiente opción:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid
Podés generar miles de millones de ID únicos con muy pocas líneas de código.